# java change appearance of checkbox in JCheckBoxMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

How can I change the default checkbox appearance of a JCheckBoxMenuItem?
I currently have [image: default], but I want it to look like [image: desired], which I strongly believe not to be custom as I have seen it numerous times already.

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem check = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Title");
```

Comment: *which I strongly believe not to be custom* - each LAF can paint the component differently. So, yes, you may have seen it before but you should not attempt to mix and match LAF. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Set The Look And Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) if you want to try another LAF for ALL components.

Comment: thank you, that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As camickr proposed in the comment, needed to set the Look and Feel (L&F) for my application.
See [How to Set The Look And Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for further explanation.
The L&F I had in mind was the 'SystemLookAndFeel' on Windows.